# Step Into Error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I installed Eclipse and am having an issue with the step into function. Usually, if I want to hit F5 to step into a function, regardless of whether we can actually step into it, Eclipse would execute the line.

For instance, when debugging at the line "Log.d("hello1", "world");", if I hit F5, I get an error. The ClassLoader.class screen opens up and says that "The source attachment does not contain the source for the file ClassLoader.class. You can change the source attachment by clicking Change Attached Source Below"

If however, I step into the line "helloWorld();", it then steps into the function.

Previously, I would be able to run through a program line by line after a break point by hitting "F5" but this no longer appears to be possible. What is the cause and remedy? I know I changed a .jar earlier when trying to fix it, and I'm not sure if I somehow made it worse.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("hello1", "world");
    helloWorld();
}

public void helloWorld(){
    Log.d("hello2", "world");
}

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause, helloworld() is a function of your own project. Log is a class not declared in your own project but only used. Attach the jar with the Log class inside it to fix it.

Comment: But it's also an issue if I were to step into "super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);" or "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);" Also, android.util.Log has been imported.